# Truncate strings in visual basic excel macro

Tags: string, excel, vba

I have a column of data that contains different length strings, separated by commas.

Here are some samples:

Row 1: Mr Smith, James New, Paul Simon
Row 2: Craig David
Row 3: Steven Smith, Luke O'Connor, Philip
Row 4: Niall, Mrs Ryan
Row 5: xyz, abc

I need to write a macro that will automatically remove all text except the last string in the cell, i.e it should keep all characters to the right of the last comma.

In the above example, the end result would be:

Row 1: Paul Simon
Row 2: Craig David
Row 3: Philip
Row 4: Mrs Ryan
Row 5: abc

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not quite what I am after any my example may have been confusing!

Comment: I can try and explain the requirement again.

Answer (score 1):

You above expected result example seems off?? Anyways here is code to get you started, I pulled out the last name for each person. Once it hits the comma it moves back and gets the string until it reaches a space.

Add a text box and label to an access form, past in the above in to the text box and your label will result as follows

Smith New Smith O'Connor Niall Ryan

```js
    Dim result As String
    Dim myarray
    myarray = Split(Me.Text1, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(myarray)
        Dim lastNameTemp
        lastNameTemp = Split(myarray(i), " ")
        Dim lastName As String
        lastName = lastNameTemp(UBound(lastNameTemp))
        result = result & " " & lastName
    Next
    
    Me.Label1.Caption = Trim(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have updated my question so its a bit clearer now what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: OK is straight forward all you need is the last string after the comma so the code is as follows 

    Dim result As String
    Dim myarray
    myarray = Split(Me.Text1, ",")
    result = myarray(UBound(myarray))
    Me.Label7.Caption = Trim(result)  

The code will pull the last string after the comma if it exists otherwise it pulls the string. Now all you have to do is loop through the records. Let me kno if you need more help

Comment: Thanks so much! How do I loop through all records in the column ?

Comment: What are you looping through? A sql database, an access database, a textfile, a textbox???

Comment: Need to loop through rows in an excel column

Answer (score 0):

OK is straight forward all you need is the last string after the comma so the code is as follows

```js
    Dim result As String
    Dim myarray
    myarray = Split(Me.Text1, ",")
    result = myarray(UBound(myarray))
    Me.Label7.Caption = Trim(result)
```

The code will pull the last string after the comma if it exists otherwise it pulls the string. Now all you have to do is loop through the records. Let me know if you need more help –

Answer (score 0):

I placed the 5 rows in cell A1, A2, A3, A4 and A5. I added a button to the excel file and the code is below. Output as expected. Let me know if you require any more assistance. Comments are lines beginning with quote.

```js
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
    NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    ' Select cell a1.
    Range("A1").Select
    ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
    For x = 1 To NumRows
        Dim theCellValue
        theCellValue = ActiveCell
        Dim result As String
        Dim myarray
        myarray = Split(theCellValue, ",")
        result = myarray(UBound(myarray))
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).value = Trim(result)
        ' Selects cell down 1 row from active cell.
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next
End Sub
```